# Find minimum number of nodes that can serve all my items

Tags: algorithm

I have some shop and some items And I want to ship all item from a minimum number of the shop.

For Exm:

I have 3 shop(s1,s2,s3) and  4 items (p1,p2,p3,p4).

And these shop having any subset of my item set.

For Exm .

s1 having (p1,p3);

s2 having (p2,p4);

s3 having (p2,p3,p4);

so minimum shop that can serve all my item would be:

(s1,s3).

I have done brute force to check all possible combinations of shops and find the minimum. but it is taking so much time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Set<String>> buckets = new HashMap<>();
    buckets.putIfAbsent("s1", new HashSet<>());
    buckets.putIfAbsent("s2", new HashSet<>());
    buckets.putIfAbsent("s3", new HashSet<>());
    buckets.get("s1").add("p1");
    buckets.get("s1").add("p3");

    buckets.get("s2").add("p2");
    buckets.get("s2").add("p4");

    buckets.get("s3").add("p2");
    buckets.get("s3").add("p3");
    buckets.get("s3").add("p4");

    Set<String> allsku = new HashSet<>();
    for (String node : buckets.keySet()) {
        allsku.addAll(buckets.get(node));
    }

    Long val = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Set<String> result = getBestCmnm(buckets, new HashSet<>(), allsku);
    System.out.println(result + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - val));
}


static Set<String> getBestCmnm(Map<String, Set<String>> buckets, Set<String> choosedNode, Set<String> remainingSku) {
    if (remainingSku.size() == 0) {
        return choosedNode;
    }
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> presentNode = new HashSet<>(buckets.keySet());
    presentNode.removeAll(choosedNode);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (String node : presentNode) {
        if (containAny(buckets.get(node), remainingSku)) {
            Set<String> choosedNode1 = new HashSet<>(choosedNode);
            choosedNode1.add(node);
            Set<String> remainingSku1 = new HashSet<>(remainingSku);
            remainingSku1.removeAll(buckets.get(node));
            Set<String> val = getBestCmnm(buckets, choosedNode1, remainingSku1);
            if (val.size() < min) {
                min = val.size();
                result = val;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean containAny(Set<String> from, Set<String> to) {
    for (String f : to) {
        if (from.contains(f)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are the constraints? like what is max number of shops/items can be in worst case?

Comment: No max limit.  I have to find min number of the shop to fulfill my order. If there are 100 shop and 100 items and if one shop has 1 unique item, then minimum will be 100.

Comment: Sounds like an [minimal cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Answer (score 1):

This is the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), isomorphic to the "vertex cover problem".  All the solutions I've seen work with a matrix denoting which sets cover which items:

```
     p1  p2  p3  p4
s1   x   -   x   -
s2   -   x   -   x
s3   -   x   x   x
```

First, note that you have *two* optimal solutions to your case: (s1, s2) and (s1, s3).  If you have an additional optimization that the sum of all set sizes be minimized (as a tiebreaker among multiple minimum-set-count solutions), then you have a larger problem to attack.

As you scan the solutions, beware of the "greedy algorithm".  It's the easiest to explain, has a good algorithmic complexity, and gives a good approximation -- but is trivial to prove to be sub-optimal.

"Greedy" is measured by choosing the set that covers the largest quantity of products.  Then you remove that set and those products from the problem space and recur on the remaining problem.

In your case, this is trivial: `s3` covers the most -- 3 products.  You put `s3` into the solution set, remove `p2 p3 p4` from the needs, and you're now left with a 2x1 matrix:

```
    p1
s1   x
s2   -
```

This gives the solution `{s1, s3}`.

---

**Preprocess**

For whatever input you get, make sure you reduce the problem size with some trivial pre-processing.  Unless you need the secondary optimization (smallest count) as well, look for subsets: remove any set that is a subset of another.

Most of all, at each phase, you take (as part of the solution) any set that is the only provider of any product.  In your posted example, you would immediately put `s1` into the solution, as it's the only provider of `p1`.  This would also remove `p3` from the problem space, leaving you with

```
    p2  p4
s2   x   x
s3   x   x
```

... and either supplier finishes the problem.

---

Once you've reached the point of multiple suppliers for each remaining product, you move into the heuristic area.  I haven't been able to find the reference for one very nice solution; it uses intelligent backtracking.

Count the number of suppliers for each product and find the minimum.  Choose one product in this minimum set.  Iterate through the suppliers for this product (sorting in greedy order can help) and choose each in turn as this product's supplier.  Remove the supplier and products from the problem space and recur.

Do this depth-first.  Keep track of the best solution found so far; pass that as a parameter in the backtracking, so you can also chop off any branch that fails to equal the existing solution's depth.

---

I hope this gets you moving toward a good solution.